# Cannot RDC a Win10 client machine

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

In our Windows SBS 2011 network with about a ten Windows 10 1803 client machines, we cannot connect to one of them using Remote Desktop Connection. The error is the following:

[image]

Here are the Firewall settings of the **problematic** PC:

[image]

Here are the Firewall settings of other clients, where the connection can be successfully established.

[image]

How do I replicate the same settings on the problematic machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Which network profile is active on the problematic machine? Domain, Private or Public? And is RDP enabled?

Comment: As you can see in the first picture, the `Domain` one. Yes RDP is enabled.

Comment: The picture only shows that the firewall is open for domain networks. It does not show which profile is active on the network interface.

Comment: Please link a picture/link to instructions on how to check this setting.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that Group Policy is not being applied to the machine in question. The firewall rules are being configured via GPO as on the second machine, bit not the first. Figure that out and you'll probably figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks, can you link me some instructions on how to configure GPO in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RemoteDesktopConnection with the machine IP worked. So we investigated inside the Windows Server `DNS Manager` and discovered that the IP used was assigned to a different machine name. Deleting one record and changing the IP address in the correct machine name resolved the issue.

Just to recap, the machine name and the network IP address did not refer to the same PC inside the `DNS Manager`.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that the firewall exception is only configured for Domain networks. Windows 10 1803 made it pretty difficult to check the currently active connection profile, the easiest way is to do this via powershell:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetConnectionProfile
Name             : example.com
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 3
InterfaceIndex   : 10
NetworkCategory  : DomainAuthenticated
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

You will get errors for interfaces that are not connected, you can safely ignore them. Relevant is the attribute `NetworkCategory`. If it shows `DomainAuthenticated` it's seen as a domain network and the firewall exception should work. If you get a different value you either have to fix the network detection, or configure the firewall to allow RDP on other profiles.

---

The second thing to check, is if remote connections are allowed at all. Again, Windows 10 1803 made it difficult to find the dialog for this. The easiest way is to just run `sysdm.cpl`. (You can do this right from the powershell, or from the run dialog, it doesn't matter).

Open the `Remote` tab and check if the `Remote Desktop` section allows connections.

[image]

Comment: Got this tested and the results are identical to yours, with the only difference that `example.com` is `example.local` as in all our client machines.